# I have a problem with "Create an Azure AD App" Specifically with the powershell Script "Create-AADIdentityApp.ps1"

Tags: deployment, scripting, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-stack

I have installed Azure stack development kit and i am trying to install the App service.
Then when i have to run the PS1 script `Create-AADIdentityApp.ps1` i fill in the following parameters

```
DirectoryTenantName
AdminArmEndpoint
TenantArmEndpoint
CertificateFilePath
```

Then i get the following error

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "3" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified.
"
At C:\app-service-certificate-install\Create-AADIdentityApp.ps1:81 char:24
    + ... rtificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates. ...
    +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

does anyone have any experience?

Answer (score 0):

You provided a invalid `CertificateFilePath`.

It should be **Full path** to the identity application [certificate file generated earlier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-app-service-before-you-get-started?view=azs-2002&pivots=state-disconnected#certificates-required-for-asdk-deployment-of-azure-app-service).

Please check and correct it.

Comment: I did I put C:\app-service-certificate-install\sso.appservice.************.onmicrosoft.com.pfx the script to create the certificates placed my asdk directory name in the certificate. but same error